# Rails 4 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error when cookies are not accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies, csrf

Using `protect_from_forgery` in Rails 4 seems to always expect a cookie, otherwise `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` is raised when using

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

if no cookies are accepted by the browser.

Are there any alternative ways to do CSRF when cookies are not accepted?
As of now I am opting for a user notice that *cookies are required*. 
Is that the right approach?

Comment: are you making `json` request?

Comment: nope I am doing mostly XHR with standard form submits, currently I am running with protect_from_forgery with: :null_session since I don't have a login, works fine but ...